# netcat getting connection timeout to specific ports alone

Tags: netcat, connection-timeout

I am trying to connect from my kubernetes cluster to a port which is used by nginx service running on abc server. The command which I used is `nc -v <server-ip> 8080`. I could see the below output

```
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connection timed out.
```

But when I try to connect to http port (80) on the same abc server, it got connected.

```
nc -v <server-ip> 80
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to <server-ip>:80.
```

port in listen mode on server abc:

```
netstat -alpn | grep 8080
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2316/nginx: master
```

What could be the reason for this issue? How can I debug this issue? It would be really helpful if someone suggests me how to find the root cause for this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is any firewall blocking traffic to that port?

Comment: @NicholasObert Checked by stopping firewall service on my abc server. Still facing same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding outbound traffic rule in security groups this issue if fixed